# Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test

Tags: php, httprequest, infobip, infobip-api

In my website am using **infobip 2-Factor Authentication** for security purpose. I got some code in their website it showing error like

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\OTP\send.php on line 2
```

Code is following:

**Send.php**

```
<?php
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://oneapi.infobip.com/2fa/1/pin');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);
$request->setHeaders(array
  ('accept' => 'application/json'
  ,'content-type' => 'application/json'
  ,'authorization' => 'App SECRET_KEY'));
  $request->setBody('{
  "applicationId": "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID",
  "messageId": "YOUR_MESSAGE_ID",
  "to": "PHONE_NUMBER"
}');

try
    {
        $response = $request->send();
        echo $response->getBody();
    } 
    catch (HttpException $ex) 
    {
        echo $ex;
    }
?>
```

This following code for request and this also showing

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\OTP\request.php on line 3
```

**request.php**

```
<?php
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://oneapi.infobip.com/2fa/1/pin/{PIN_ID}/verify');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);
$request->setHeaders(array('accept' => 'application/json', 'content-type' => 'application/json','authorization' => 'App YOUR_API_KEY'
));
$request->setBody('{"pin": "PIN_CODE"}');

try
   {
       $response = $request->send();
       echo $response->getBody();
   }   
   catch (HttpException $ex) 
   {
       echo $ex;
   }
?>
```

Comment: this is because the file containing that class has not been loaded yet with include or require.  Literally class HttpRequest means nothing to php until it is included.

Comment: you mean i want to add some file here...?

Comment: you would hopefully have the file containing that class and then add somthing like include 'pathtoHttpReques';

Comment: @NishaChinnapa Are you trying those codes in local ? I mean in `localhost` ?

Comment: @sulthan yes am using in localhost

Comment: This might be the problem `Not including the appropriate file or mismatch path, (Infobip will have a bulk of folders for sending sms)` **Advice** Try to trigger the file in online, also i believe you installed infobip by `composer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok say you have a file HttpRequest.php in the same folder and in that file is

```
 class HttpRequest {
    ...
}
```

Then somewhere before calling it, you need to tell php about it. This is done using one of four ways, but I would do it this way

```
require_once __DIR__.'/HttpRequest.php'; //assuming it's in the same folder.
```

Remember this isn't magic, it's just computer code.  It only knows what you tell it.  I would also hope that the place you got the code from would have some kind of basic instructions on how to install set it up, and that you read that.

Now not to confuse you but the choices are

```
include
include_once
require
require_once
```

I only put these here to illustrate that, things ( generally ) mean what they say in programing.  So include, includes it, adding *_once, only does it once, and require will throw an error if it's not found in the location specified, thus making it required.  Whereas include doesn't really care if it was actually included or not.

Good Luck! happy coding.